# How do I send default data with jQuery AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, post

I have a form full of inputs, I want to send them along with a specialVariable (see below) in the same AJAX request, how do I do that?

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: { 
        somethingSpecial: specialVariable"        
    }
})
```

Comment: You could do two things: 1.) add special variable to the form (e.g. via dom manipulation and adding a hidden input) or 2.) serialize the form using http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/ , add your value to the serialized and post this object as `data`

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize the form's data into an array using jQuery's `serializeArray()` function:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { somethingSpecial: specialVariable, formData: $('form').serializeArray() }
});
```

See the jQuery docs [here](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) to get form data as an array and then [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) any additional fields into that array, and then use [`$.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) to pass the array as an ajax-friendly string to the `data` property:

```
var formData = $('#yourForm').serializeArray();

var specialField = {};
specialField.name = "somethingSpecial";
specialField.value = "specialVariable";
formData.push(specialField);

$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: $.param(formData)
})
```